# Is there a way to pause with the spotify api?

Tags: javascript, spotify

I want to be able to pause the current track but can't seem to find any method of doing so.

Documentation is here: http://developer.spotify.com/download/spotify-apps-api/reference/

Am using the following to play a track...

`m.player.play(uri)`

but there doesn't seem to be an equivalent `m.player.pause(uri)` or similar...

Comment: I know this comment might be a little late, but I can't seem to figure it our. Where is the url to the library that allowed you to import all these objects and methods? I can't seem to find it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use this:

```
m.player.playing = 0;
```

Read here about the player: 
https://developer.spotify.com/docs/apps/api/0.1/f19ff300f8.html

Comment: Here's another example of how to build a play/pause toggle: https://github.com/ptrwtts/kitchensink/blob/master/js/player.js#L17

Comment: Here's a new link: https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/apps/docs/ca28d10757.html