# How to resume a song?

Tags: spotify, resume

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to pause with the spotify api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8850346/is-there-a-way-to-pause-with-the-spotify-api)

I'm working on Spotify in-app application.

I like to implement play, pause, and resume functionalities.

I can stop a song using **playing(false)** setter as indicated on https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/apps/docs/beta/f19ff300f8.html

I can play a song using **play()** method.

I can't find a way to pause then resume.

Is there a method or hack or workaround?!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8850346/is-there-a-way-to-pause-with-the-spotify-api

Comment: @cornbreadninja // great!!! thank you! I thought that stops a song.

Answer (score 2):

`m.player.playing = false;` pauses.

`m.player.playing = true;` resumes.